# mongodb mongoTemplate get distinct field with some criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongodb

My MongoDB json structure is

```
 {
    "_id" : "122134231234234",
    "name" : "Total_pop",
    "description" : "sales category",
    "source" : "public",
    "dataset" :"d1"


},
{
    "_id" : "1123421231234234",
    "name" : "Total_pop",
    "description" : "sales category",
    "source" : "public",
    "dataset" :"d1"


},
{
    "_id" : "12312342332423343",
    "name" : "Total_pop",
    "description" : "sales category",
    "source" : "private",
    "description" : "d1"
}
```

I need to get collection distinct of dataset where source is public.
I tried this query, and it didn't work:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.where("source").in("public");     
query.addCriteria(criteria);
query.fields().include("name");
query.fields().include("description");
query.fields().include("description");
query.fields().include("source"); List list =
mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionname").distinct("source", query);
```

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For one thing the `.getCollection()` method returns the basic Driver collection object like so:

```
DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName");
```

So the type of query object might be different from what you are using, but there are also some other things. Namely that `.distinct()` only returns the "distint" values of the key that you asked for, and doe not return other fields of the document. So you could do:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.where("dataset").is("d1");
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(criteria);
List list = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName")
    .distinct("source",query.getQueryObject());
```

But that is only going to return "sample" as a single element in the list for instance.

If you want the "fields" from a distinct set then use the `.aggregate()` method instead. With either the "first" occurances of the other field values for the distinct key:

```
    DBCollection colllection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName");

    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.<DBObject>asList(
        new BasicDBObject("$match",new BasicDBObject("dataset","d1")),
        new BasicDBObject("$group",
            new BasicDBObject("_id","$source")
                .append("name",new BasicDBObject("$first","$name"))
                .append("description", new BasicDBObject("$first","$description"))
        )
    );

    AggregationOutput output = colllection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Or the actual "distinct" values of multiple fields, by making them all part of the grouping key:

```
    DBCollection colllection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName");

    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.<DBObject>asList(
        new BasicDBObject("$match",new BasicDBObject("dataset","d1")),
        new BasicDBObject("$group",
            new BasicDBObject("_id",
                new BasicDBObject("source","$source")
                    .append("name","$name")
                    .append("description","$description")
            )
        )
    );

    AggregationOutput output = colllection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

There are also a direct `.aggregate()` method on mongoTemplate instances already, which has a number of helper methods to build pipelines. But this should point you in the right direction at least.

Comment: This doesn't works in my case: `mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName")
    .distinct("source",query.getQueryObject());`

Comment: why can't we get a list of the entire object / entity by a field in a distinct way? why only by one field?

Answer (score 10):

As of Spring Data Mongo 2.2.0 MongoTemplate provides a function to retrieve the distinct field with criteria,

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria("country").is("IN");
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(criteria);
return mongoTemplate.findDistinct(query,"city",Address.class,String.class);
```

Which basically finds all the distinct cities in address collection where country is IN.