# Spring Data Mongo - Query methods and Distinct field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm currently working on a project using Spring Data Mongo.
My repository is just an interface extending MongoRepository. I would like to add a custom query method in order to retrieve all distinct values for one of my collection's fields.

I tried something like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "devices", collectionResourceRel = "deviceInfos")
public interface DeviceInfoRepository extends MongoRepository<DeviceInfo, String> {

    @RestResource(path = "distinctUnitIds")
    List<String> findDistinctUnitIdBy();

}
```

With that code, Spring give me an error because it's not able to build my list. So I tried this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "devices", collectionResourceRel = "deviceInfos")
public interface DeviceInfoRepository extends MongoRepository<DeviceInfo, String> {

    @RestResource(path = "distinctUnitIds")
    List<DeviceInfo> findDistinctUnitIdBy();

}
```

That code works but the distinct seems to be totally ignored.

The documentation about Distinct in query method is really not clear...

Did I do something wrong? What's the best way to solve get the distinct values of a field using Spring Data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use Spring Data `MongoTemplate` - the `MongoRepository` interfaces are made only for basic functionality and for more fine grain control of what you are querying, its best to use `MongoTemplate`.

Here is an example of how one would get distinct values from a collection:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.where("dataset").is("d1");
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(criteria);
List list = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName")
    .distinct("source",query.getQueryObject());
```

Here is the link to more info: [mongodb mongoTemplate get distinct field with some criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635677/mongodb-mongotemplate-get-distinct-field-with-some-criteria)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was expecting something like that. Any idea of what the findDistinctBy described in the reference guide does?

Comment: The keyword distinct is not supported in mongo repositories, check the supported keywords here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries

Answer (score 2):

in SpringBoot2 you can do the following :

```
DistinctIterable<String> iterable = mongoTemplate.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).distinct("source",in(FieldValue,query.getQueryObject(), String.class);
        MongoCursor<String> cursor = iterable.iterator();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            list.add(cursor.next());
        }
        return list;
```

Comment: I am not clear with your answer. Could you please post complete solution?

Comment: Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535331/spring-data-mongo-issue-with-distinct-collection ?

Comment: @PAA Both pretty same, except the above example uses an iterator to support scalability- which is advisable. Let me know if you still have any question