# Grouping by property using Mongo repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

I use the Java Spring MongoDB repository in my project.

I have this collection in MongoDB called Info:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "hosting" : "hostgator.com", count:7 }
{ "_id" : 2, "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com", count:7}
{ "_id" : 3, "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com", count:3}
{ "_id" : 4, "hosting" : "hostgator.com", count:5 }
{ "_id" : 5, "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com", count:1 }
{ "_id" : 6, "hosting" : "cloud.google.com", count:1 }
{ "_id" : 7, "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com", count:5 }
{ "_id" : 8, "hosting" : "hostgator.com", count:2 }
{ "_id" : 9, "hosting" : "cloud.google.com", count:3 }
{ "_id" : 10,"hosting" : "godaddy.com", count:7 }
...
{ "_id" : 100, "hosting" : "godaddy.com", count:5 }
```

Here is DTO definition:

```
public class Info{
    public int _id;
    public String hosting;
    public int count;
}
```

I need to write a query and to get from the database all values of count property and remove the duplications. For example, the result that I expect according to the collection above is:

```
List<int> counts = [1,2,3,5,7];
```

For this purpose I use the aggregation group method and MongoTemplate:

```
        GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("count");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupOperation);
        var result = template.aggregate(aggregation, Info.class,  Info[].class);
        System.out.println(result.getMappedResults());
```

But the result that I get is an empty array - [].

Why I don't get the expected result?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46890137/2282634.  You should group by hosting and use $first to get a single count.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring mongodb - group operation after unwind - can not find $first or $push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888425/spring-mongodb-group-operation-after-unwind-can-not-find-first-or-push)

Comment: You can try this Spring data query: [How to write a query to get distinct values from mongodb collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412093/how-to-write-a-query-to-get-distinct-values-from-mongodb-collection/66423381#66423381)

Comment: @prasad_ amazing! It works perfect thank you!
In case if I want to add a filter by some property for example where hosting property-specific value how can i add it to annotation?

Comment: You can add a `$match` stage before the `$group`. See examples using multiple pipeline stages at [Spring Data MongoDB - @Aggregate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/api/) .