# Mongo DB / No duplicates

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

I have have a mongo collection that keeps state records for devices. Thus, there could be multiple records per device. What I would like to do is create a query through the mongoTemplate that gets the latest record for each device.

Here's the constraints:

- Pass in a Set<'String'> name_ids, regular field within mongo collection not the _id or found within the _id
- get only the latest record for each device with matching name_id
- return List<'DeviceStateData'> (No duplicates should be found with the same name_id)

example of collection object:

```
{
  _id: "241324123412",
  name_id: "flyingMan",
  powerState:"ON",
  timeStamp: ISODate('')
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should look on [Distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635677/mongodb-mongotemplate-get-distinct-field-with-some-criteria) you can find details with Spring.